# How do I successfully connect intellij to remote websphere?

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere

I'm currently trying to connect my intellij installation to a remote websphere server (version 8.5.5.14). When I start making the configuration it gives me a message "Username but no password specified". The thing is, there's no password input in the form. So how do I specify the password?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent versions, IDEA ensures that the plain passwords are never stored in the project- or application- level configuration files. All the passwords previously stored in the application servers run configurations should be automatically moved to KeePass manager or Mac Keychain after an opening of the project.

We also decided to not allow to specify passwords in the template run configurations, so your screenshot is as expected.

There was a [bug preventing the passwords fields from showing up](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209284) in the normal non- template run configurations, but it should be fixed in the final builds for 2018.3.6 and 2019.1 streams